# Let $a$ and $b$ be coprime positive integers. Prove that, for any integer $n$, there exist integers $s$ and $t$ such that $sa + tb = n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I always sort of took this fact for (well..) fact.  Can someone help me with the proof?
Does this question have something to do with modulus? Since $a$ and $b$ are coprime ($gcd$ = 1), multiplying them by different parameters $(s,t)$ can somehow lead to any integer $n$?

Help please? Proofs homework question.

Comment: Prove that there exists $m,n$ such that $ma + nb=1$ and the result will follow.

Comment: So, since $hcf(a,b)=1$ there exists integers $c$and $d$ such that $ac + bd = 1$, thus, $nac + nbd = n$. $s=cn$ and $t=dn$.  Proven?

Comment: Yes, modulo the transposition error in the typography of gcd ;)

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

(1)  Use Bezout's Identity to express $\;(a,b)=1\;$

(2)  Now multiply the above by $\;n\;$ ...